# WMV encoding using Media Foudation: specifying "Number of B Frames"

Tags: windows, wmv, ms-media-foundation

I am encoding video to WMV using Media Foundation SDK.  I see that the number of B frames can be set using a property, but I have no clue how/where to set it.

That property is called MFPKEY_NUMBFRAMES and is described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819354%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Our code does roughly the following:

- call MFStartup
- call MFCreateAttributes once so we can set muxer, video and audio attributes
- configure the IMFAttributes created in the previous step, for example by setting the video bitrate: pVideoOverrides->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, m_iVideoBitrateBPS);
- create sink writer by calling IMFReadWriteClassFactory::CreateInstanceFromURL
- for each frame, call WriteSample on the sink writer
- call MFShutdown

Am I supposed to set the b-frames property on the IMFAttribute on which I also set the video bitrate?

Answer (score 1):

The property is applicable to [Windows Media Video 9 Encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That is, you need to locate it on your topology and adjust the property there. Other topology elements (e.g. multiplexer) might accept other properties, but this one has no effect there.

MSDN gives you step by st4ep instructions in [Configuring a WMV Encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742787%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and where it says

> To specify the target bitrate, set the `MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE` attribute on the media type.

You can also alter other encoder properties. There is also step by step detailed [Tutorial: 1-Pass Windows Media Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which shows the steps of the entire process.

Comment: Thanks... I don't build any topology directly, I only have an IMFSinkWriter and some IMFAttributes.  How can I get access to the WMV9 Encoder?

Comment: Also the tutorial link does't build (see comments at the bottom of that web page) and can only convert from a source file.  I need to be able to feed in uncompressed video and audio samples